# How to get constraintName on DataIntegrityViolationException using H2 database?

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm using PostgreSQL on production and H2 on development.

I handle `DataIntegrityViolationException` in a SpringBoot ControllerAdvice and I want to get the name of the constraint that drives to this exception.

My table is defined like that :

```
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "users_unique_email_idx", columnNames = {"email"})
})
class User ...
```

When I use PostgreSQL it works perfectly. I get the cause of exception which is a `ConstraintViolationException` and then get the constraint name. Something like that :

```
((ConstraintViolationException)ex.getCause()).getConstraintName()
```

But using H2 Database I can't find a way to get the constraintName. The `DataIntegrityViolationException` doesn't contain the `ConstraintViolationException` or the constraintName. With H2 the error message is empty :

```
DataIntegrityViolationException:
  could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];
Caused by:
  JdbcSQLException: Violation dindex unique ou clé primaire: {0}
  Unique index or primary key violation: {0}; SQL statement:
```

Note : In my H2 `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINTS` table my constraint on email field exists and has the good name (`users_unique_email_idx`)

Is it a limitation of H2 Database ?
How can I enable constraint name in H2 ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Its a bug, no solution for now. It works once in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is
Hibernate translate PostgreSQL contraints exception base on database messages.
In class `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect` we can find a object`TemplatedViolatedConstraintNameExtracter` that checks if the message from database contains string `violates unique constraint`.
if you changed the language for database, hibernate cannot translate the exception because it is based on English. This is the reason why Hibernate cannot find the constraint name.
There are 2 solutions:

1. Change environment variables **LC_MESSAGES** to English. messages from PostgreSQL will be presented in English.
2. Extend PostgreSQL dialect class (there are few classes depends on PostgreSQL version) and override `getViolatedConstraintNameExtracter`. Create your own `ViolatedConstraintNameExtracter` object than will translate your language.

In H2 Database case check according to above.

Comment: Yes ! Answer from H2 team is here too : https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1487 It was a bug. Suppose to be fixed now.